# Doctrine array hydration with all fields?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

The following code would be a good way to get all fields of an entity? including association id's, as they are in the database.

```
$entity_class = 'Entity\User';
$allFields = $this->get_select_fields($entity_class, 'u');

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select($allFields)
   ->from($entity_class, 'u');

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

Return example of get_select_fields(): 'u.id,u.name,u.email,IDENTITY(u.role) as role'

```
protected function get_select_fields($entityClass, $entityAlias = 'e', $skip = array())
{
    $associationMappings = true;
    $metadata = $this->em->getClassMetadata($entityClass);
    $select = array();

    $properties = $metadata->getFieldNames();
    foreach($properties as $fieldName){
        if(!in_array($fieldName, $skip)){
            $field = $entityAlias.'.'.$fieldName;
            array_push($select, $field);
        }
    }

    if($associationMappings){
        //$mappings = $metadata->getAssociationMappings();
        $properties = $metadata->getAssociationNames();
        foreach($properties as $fieldName){
            if(!in_array($fieldName, $skip)){
                $field = "IDENTITY({$entityAlias}.{$fieldName}) as {$fieldName}";
                array_push($select, $field);
            }
        }
    }

    $result = implode(',', $select);

    return $result;        
}
```

Thanks!